# What's different between "isset($string)" & "@$string" on PHP?

Tags: php

What's different between `isset($string)` and `@$string` in PHP ?

This works both ways, so what's the difference?

```
if(isset($string))
 ....


if(@$string)
 ....
```

Comment: The first checks that the variable is defined, and not null. The second is checking it for a truthy value, the `@` sign suppresses any errors

Comment: so can we use both ? isset(@$string) ?

Comment: @Abudayah `isset(@$string)` wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Abudayah: The [`@` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is used to suppress any errors that would come from the following statement.  It is *highly* suggested to ***never*** use the `@` operator.  It hides any and all errors that would appear on the line.  If `$string` isn't set, then `if($string)` would throw a warning (and still be `false` because the `if` converts `$string` to a boolean).  The `@` hides that.

Comment: Also, try this with different values, you'll see they are not the same at all.  Try `$string = '';`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - For a full list of comparisons, [see this list](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).  `$string = "0";` passes `isset`, but not `@$str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `isset()` check variable and return true if variable exists. Sign `@` ignore error. Give almost the same values. Next code maybe show it:

```
   if(isset($string))
      print 1; // no print
   if(@$string)
      print 2; // no print

   $string = false;
   if(isset($string))
      print 3; // print 3
   if(@$string)
      print 4; // no print
```

Comment: FYI: The triple backticks only works on GitHub's markdown, not here.

Comment: Okay, I will try remember it :)

Answer (score 6):

1. `isset` is `true` if the given variable exists *and is not `null`*.
   `@$var` is `true` if the value of `$var` *is `true` in a loose comparison*.*
   `!== null` and `== true` matches different values.
2. In the case of `@$var`, if `$var` does not exist, an error will be generated internally and raised and its output suppressed through `@`. This is a much more expensive operation, and it may trigger custom defined error handlers on the way. Do not ever use it if there's an alternative.

* A non-existent variable's value is substituted by `null`, which equals `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `isset($str)` **is not the same** as `@$str`.

`isset($str)` is true if `$str` [is set and is not null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).
`@$str` is true if `$str` is [truthy](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Consider the following example:

```
$str = "0";

if (isset($str)) {
    // This gets printed because $str is set
    echo "Str is set" . PHP_EOL;
}

if (@$str) {
    // This is NOT printed because $str is falsy
    echo "Str is truthy" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

It should also be noted that `@`, in addition to being a bad habit, incurs a [significant performance penalty](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance).